# How to get coordinates of an address in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

How do i get gps co-ordinates of the location/address entered by user in android ?

Comment: I ll not find the accurate ans so .. @herschel

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(<your context>);  
List<Address> addresses;
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(<String address>, 1);
if(addresses.size() > 0) {
    double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
    double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: @natali I want to say one thing ...hmmmmm your profile image is very very very.... cute :)..

Answer (score 11):

You can use Android's `Geocoder` to do reverse geocoding:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(myLocation, 1);
Address address = addresses.get(0);
double longitude = address.getLongitude();
double latitude = address.getLatitude();
```

Also include the following in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Also note that you need to be using an API which includes a `Geocoder` implementation. APIs which include this are the Android Google APIs for example. You can use `Geocoder.isPresent()` to check if an implementation exists for your targeted API.

Check out the `Geocoder` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) for more information.

Comment: This did it for me :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Address> addresses;
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(<String address>, 1);
if(addresses.size() > 0){
double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
}
```

manifest permissions:-

```
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION
```

Answer (score 2):

use manifest permissions like

```
android.permission.INTERNET 
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION     
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION 
android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION
```

and go with this

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(myLocation, 1);
Address address = addresses.get(0);
if(addresses.size() > 0) {
    double latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
    double longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: Do we really need internet connectivity to decode the geo points??

Comment: @SANTHOSH Yes, of course, there's no local database of addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete sample

First define a zoom

```
    final CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5);
```

Clear any map markers

```
    mMap.clear();
    //Declare a new marker
    final MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
    //declare a EditText to get the user informed address
    EditText etEndereco = findViewById(R.id.map_prof_etEnd);

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(map_prof.this);
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(etEndereco.getText().toString(), 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        double latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
        double longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();

        mp.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

        Log.e("teste map2", "inserted latitude " + Latitude + ", inserted Longitude " + Longitude);

        mp.title("Selected location");
        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.addMarker(mp);
        mMap.moveCamera(center);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
    }
```