# get coordinates of a location by name

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, geocoding

I want to receive longitude and latitude values for a given location name in my android app. I know Google has a Geo-coding API, but it seems it enforces my to show the results on a Google map:

> the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map;
>   geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.
>   [from here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

So is there any other way to receive coordinates for a location name? or perhaps I didn't understand the TOU correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `Google's Geocoding API / google maps / any Maps API`, It is `not possible` to get location co-ordinates using location names. Even, `yahoo API doesn't give full support` for all geo location names. In yahoo, it provides location information for some popular cities only not every location. So far `google's map API is better than any other API`.

Just Hide that map view in your app, and overlay any other view you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(<your context>);  
List<Address> addresses;
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(<String address>, 1);
if(addresses.size() > 0) {
  double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
  double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
}
```

refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9698408/2458192

Answer (score 0):

The Geo-Coding and Reverse Geocoding API should be able to help you.

But in any case Yahoo! has very good Geocoding API, which can even give you response in JSON.

I have tried them and they work perfectly for such a use case.

Comment: Thank you @rock_win, but if ADR is right and yahoo doesn't provide full support for all locations I guess I'll have to stick with google's apis.